# how to use scroll in foselasticabundle?

Tags: php, elasticsearch, foselasticabundle

I would like to know how can i set scroll in foselasticabundle? I have this code

```
$res = $this->commentIndex->createSearch($query, ['scroll' => '1m']);
 $res->addType('reading');
 $res->scroll();
```

I know Im already close getting the result of my query. Can you help me which of the function in foselasticabundle I can use to display the results of my query. Im trying deep study the code of foselasticabundle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer of the issue in this [link](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle/issues/1297)

I have this code the same in the link

```
$search = $this->commentIndex->createSearch();
$search->addType('reading');
$search->setQuery($query);
$scroll = new \Elastica\Scroll($search);
$results = [];


foreach ($scroll as $scrollId => $resultSet) {
      foreach ($resultSet->getDocuments() as $doc) {
         $results[$doc->getId()] = $doc;
      }
   }
```

So far in this approach I can get the scroll id and the results i need. But if you found another way, hoping you can post it in this question.